# React Native scrollview stops scrolling after screen change

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I have a ScrollView in react native where the functionality stops working only after I change the screen. For example: when I reload and land on the home screen (with the ScrollView) it all works fine. but when I use the bottom tab navigator to change the screen and return back to the home screen, it doesn't work anymore.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
const Home = () => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.background }}>
            <Header screenName="home" />
            <View style={{ color: COLORS.secondary, flex: 14, paddingHorizontal: SIZES.width / 20}}>
                <ScrollView
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.popularHeader}>Title</Text>
                    <ScrollView
                        horizontal={true}
                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                        style={styles.popular}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.popularItem}>
                            <Text>Name</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.popularItem}>
                            <Text>Name</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.popularItem}>
                            <Text>Name</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.popularItem}>
                            <Text>Name</Text>
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                    <View style={styles.event}>
                        <Text style={styles.eventTitle}>event title</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.eventDate}>date</Text>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    popularHeader: {
        color: COLORS.text,
        fontSize: SIZES.h4,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginBottom: 10
    },
    popular: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        paddingBottom: SIZES.height / 30,
        marginBottom: SIZES.height / 30,
        borderBottomColor: COLORS.secondary
    },
    popularItem: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        borderRadius: 5,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: COLORS.text,
        marginRight: 10,
    },
    event:{
        height: SIZES.height / 3,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.text,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginBottom: SIZES.height / 30,
        padding: 10
    },
    eventTitle: {
        fontSize: SIZES.h3,
        alignSelf: 'center'
    },
    eventDate: {
        fontSize: SIZES.h6,
        alignSelf: 'center'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wonders, after a three-day-long search I found out the problem was with the bottomTabNavigator not unmounting the screens after a change of screen. so the solution that fixed my problem is:

in screenOptions:

```
unmountOnBlur: true
```